# External Eloqua Form Integration in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Has anyone successfully implemented the jQuery Eloqua plugin?

http://code.google.com/p/eloqua-tracking/w/list

I'd love to see how the data tracking / lookup javascript is implemented properly..

Eloqua's provided example with standard javascript isn't working for me -

http://topliners.eloqua.com/community/do_it/blog/2011/01/13/creating-your-own-sample-eloqua-data-lookup-script-cookie-based-for-your-developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript' LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
function SetElqContent(){
if (this.GetElqContentPersonalizationValue){
V_ElqFirstName = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_ElqFirstName'));
V_ElqLastName = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_ElqLastName'));
eMail = GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_ElqEmailAddress');
V_ElqEmailAddress = eMail;
alert('email on page V_ElqEmailAddress= ' + V_ElqEmailAddress)
alert('email on page eMail= ' + eMail)
V_ElqCompanyName = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_ElqCompanyName'));
V_ElqPhoneNumber = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_ElqPhoneNumber'));
V_Total_Visits = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_Total_Visits'));
V_Total_Pages = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_Total_Pages'));
V_LastVisitDateAndTime = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_LastVisitDateAndTime'));
V_Salesperson1p = (GetElqContentPersonalizationValue('V_Salesperson1p'));
document.write('<p><b>First Name:</b>' + V_ElqFirstName);
document.write('<p><b>Last Name:</b>' + V_ElqLastName);
document.write('<p><b>Email Address:</b>' + V_ElqEmailAddress);
document.write('<p><b>Company:</b>' + V_ElqCompanyName);
document.write('<p><b>Phone Number:</b>' + V_ElqPhoneNumber);
document.write('<p><b>Total Pages:</b>' + V_Total_Pages);
document.write('<p><b>Total Visits:</b>' + V_Total_Visits);
document.write('<p><b>Last Visit:</b>' + V_LastVisitDateAndTime);
document.write('<p><b>Salesperson:</b>' + V_Salesperson1p);
} else {
document.write('<p><b>Personalization functions not found</b><p>');
}
}
</SCRIPT>

<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='elqNow/elqCfg.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='elqNow/elqImg.js'></script>
<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript' LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
elqPPS = '50';
elqDLKey = escape('9adf75e2f3cb4a1b9c5f344d68342356');
elqDLLookup = '';
</SCRIPT>
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='elqNow/elqCPers.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```